# Losing customer details when navigating between pages in Blazor MAUI application

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm developing a Blazor MAUI application where I have an order object (PosOrder) that needs to store both the company and customer details. The order object is managed by a service class (PosOrderService), and I'm encountering an issue where the customer details are getting lost when navigating from the login page to the home page.

Here's an overview of my implementation:

```
public class PosOrder
```

{
// Other properties...

```
public Company Company { get; set; }
public Customer Customer { get; set; }

public PosOrder()
{
    // Initialize other properties...

    Company = new Company();
    Customer = new Customer();
}
```

}

In the login page, I retrieve the PosOrderService instance and update the company details using the PosOrderService.UpdateOrder method. This works fine, and I can see the updated company details in the order object.

However, when I navigate to the home page and retrieve the PosOrderService instance again, I notice that the customer details are no longer present in the order object. It seems like the customer details are lost during the navigation process.

```
public class PosOrderService
{
    private PosOrder _order;

    public PosOrderService()
    {
        // Initialize the order object
        _order = new PosOrder();
    }

    public PosOrder GetOrder()
    {
        return _order;
    }

    public void UpdateOrder(PosOrder updatedOrder)
    {
        _order = updatedOrder;
    }
}
```

this is how i call it in the login

`private PosOrderService _orderService=new PosOrderService(); PosOrder CurrentOrder = _orderService.GetOrder(); CurrentOrder.posCompany = CompanyResponse[0]; _orderService.UpdateOrder(CurrentOrder);`

this si how i call it in the home page

`PosOrder currentOrder = _orderService.GetOrder(); currentOrder.Customer = value; _orderService.UpdateOrder(currentOrder);`

I'm not sure what could be causing the customer details to be lost when navigating between pages. Is there something I'm missing or any common pitfalls I should be aware of when working with shared objects and data in Blazor?

Any insights or suggestions on how to investigate and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!